# Integrity constraint orHash code issue when saving a many to many relation in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I use spring boot 3.1.3, lombok and jpa

I try to save a many to many relation

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Pub {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_PUB", sequenceName = "SEQ_PUB", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_PUB")
    @Column(name = "ID_PUB", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    protected Long idPub;
    
   @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "PUB_CAT", schema = "",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CAT", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PUB", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Cat> cats = new HashSet<>();
    
    public void addCat(Cat cat) {
        cats.add(cat);
        cat.getPubs().add(this);
    }
    
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIE_MUSICALE", schema = "")
public class Cat {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_CATEGORIEMUSICALE", sequenceName = "SEQ_CATEGORIEMUSICALE", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_CATEGORIEMUSICALE")
    @Column(name = "ID_CATEGORIEMUSICALE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    @NotNull
    private Long idCat;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cats")
    private Set<Pub> pub = new HashSet<>();
    
}
```

I get this error

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null    at
> com.acme.pub.entity.Pub.hashCode(Pub.java:18) ~[main/:na]     at
> java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:413)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]     at
> com.acme.pub.entity.Cat.hashCode(Cat.java:28) ~[main/:na]

When i put     @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "cats") in Pub entity

> Blockquote

integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Comment: There are many questions and articles on why Lombok data is a bad with JPA entities. Having everything in an entity included in the hashcode/equals method when there are bi-directional or self referencing relationships is just bad in general - take a look at the java Lombok actually generates to see the issues it causes. As for an integrity constraint violation - you will need to put more into the question to figure out what is happening such as showing what you are saving and what you have in the DB already.